# PHP: What is fastest SOAP, file_get_contents or Curl?

Tags: soap, curl, file-get-contents

I have website A that is sending request on each page load in header to website B.
B server is doing some internal search in mysql and need to return some data to server A that will display some content based on that response.

What is the fastest way to make communication between these two servers?

Comment: It depends upon your content, I think, Curl is fast.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using file get contents or curl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844299/using-file-get-contents-or-curl)

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and easiest method is cURL and also data returned by cURL is easy to parse.
The use of get_file_contents is purely dedicated to reading of a file, while cURL is totally dedicated for communication of data between the two servers.