# Why cURL is faster than file_get_contents?

Tags: php, http, curl, libcurl

There are actually two sub questions:

1. what's the difference between PHP `curl` library and [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/)? is the PHP `curl` library just a bridge to connect and use the `libcurl` or it is `libcurl` re-written in PHP language?
2. Why `curl` is much faster than the `file_get_contents` function in PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using file get contents or curl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844299/using-file-get-contents-or-curl)

Answer (score 1):

> 1. the difference between PHP curl library and libcurl

PHP/CURL is a "binding" for the underlying libcurl library. It means that there's a bunch of glue code in the PHP curl extension that ultimately calls libcurl to actually perform the transfer operations.

The PHP code doesn't do very much more than converting from PHP conventions to libcurl conventions (and back again). It allows PHP users to take advantage of libcurl's raw native speed and latest developments without anyone having to change anything.

> 2. Why is curl faster than file_get_contents function in PHP?

Both are implemented in C and offer file transfer capabilities for PHP programs. The explanation is probably because of their respective software architectures and particular feature sets that makes one faster than the other for certain use cases.

There have possibly also been more work and efforts spent on optimizing transfer performance in libcurl.

As in most cases, it might be worth benchmarking exactly your case so that you know that you're not relying on speed tests done for cases that have other characteristics than yours.

Comment: Exactly even on Google App Engine platform file_get_contents() perform better. Here is some analysis https://blog.previewtechs.com/curl-vs-file_get_contents-google-app-engine-performance-analysis